# How to style facebook like box

Tags: facebook-likebox

I have included a Facebook Like box script code on my website. But i need to change the styles despite of being default Facebook colors and background. How is it possible. could any help me please

Comment: I think you can use it only in blue color, and light color.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly if this is what your after but the people over at Pixabay made a tutorial on how to change parts of it, perhaps the colour could go along with it?

Here you go:
[Link](http://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/how-to-style-a-facebook-like-box-with-css-30/)